# JAVA FX - Getting number of capital letters from Input

Tags: java, javafx

I have completely redone the code and it is almost complete. The last thing I am trying to figure out is how to get the number of capital letters from the string the user inputs in the program. I have correctly ran the program using Scanner and System.out without JavaFx. However, I have not figured out how to translate the code from a console input to input in a text field. Here is my new code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UppercaseLetters extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    // Create Pane
    UpperCase pane = new UpperCase();

    primaryStage.setTitle("UpperCase");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    primaryStage.show();
    }

private class UpperCase extends GridPane {
    Label lblString = new Label("Enter String:");
    Label lblAmount = new Label("Number of capital Letters:");

    TextField tfString = new TextField();
    TextField tfAmount = new TextField();

    private UpperCase() {
        setHgap(10);
        setVgap(10);
        setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        add(lblString, 0, 0);
        add(tfString, 1, 0);
        add(lblAmount, 0, 1);
        add(tfAmount, 1, 1);

        tfString.setText("0");
        tfString.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        tfAmount.setText("0");
        tfAmount.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        HBox hButtons = new HBox(submit);
        submit.setOnAction(e->{

        });



    }
}


}
```

Here is the code for the program running without JavaFx.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CapitalNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("The number of uppercase letters = " + count(s.toCharArray()));
    }

    public static int count(char[] chars) {

        return count(chars, chars.length - 1);
    }

    public static int count(char[] chars, int high) {

        int count = Character.isUpperCase(chars[high]) ? 1 : 0;
        if (high == 0)
            return count;
        else
            return count + count(chars, high - 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your inner class UpperPane should be defined within your start function

Answer (score 1):

`UpperPane`  is missing the constructor `UpperPane(int value)`. When you extract `UpperPane` out of your start method, your IDE will show the according error.

Now you need to listen to changes to your textField:

```
tfString.setOnAction(e -> {
                int count = count(tfString.getText().toCharArray());
                tfAmount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}

//or

tfString.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldText, newText) -> {
                int count = count(newText.toCharArray());
                tfAmount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
});
```

Comment: I have completely edited the code to a working program now without the jumbled mess. However, I am still struggling using the setText and getText to count the number of capital letters in the string.

Comment: I got it to work that way, but I still have to include the submit button to make that work.